# GridSearchCV with custom tune grid

Tags: scikit-learn, hyperparameter-tuning, grid-search, gridsearchcv

What is the best way to perform custom parameter search CV with the Scikit-learn API? I really like GridSearchCV. However for my case the  `param_grid` parameter is inflexible because it will search over the entire span of parameter combinations. Ideally, I would like to provide my own parameter space in a `dataframe`, one column for each parameter.

Thus, is there an appropriate class within Scikit-learn to help me achieve this result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GridSearchCV` does allow `param_grid` to be a list of grid-dicts, which sometimes is sufficient.  In this case, separate grids are generated and their union is searched.

There isn't quite a convenient implementation by which you provide your own list of hyperparameter points.  But looking at [the source code for `GridSearchCV`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/42aff4e2edd8e8887478f6ff1628f27de97be6a3/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py#L1272), you'll notice that it's amazingly sparse.  Most everything is handled by the inherited class `BaseSearchCV`.  The grid-specific stuff is also factored out:

```py
    def _run_search(self, evaluate_candidates):
        """Search all candidates in param_grid"""
        evaluate_candidates(ParameterGrid(self.param_grid))
```

The `ParameterGrid` class is what's responsible for turning the (possibly list of) dict(s) into a grid(s).

So you could probably easily write a custom class, inheriting from `BaseSearchCV`, where you pass the set of hyperparameter points you want and define `_run_search` to just evaluate each element from your set.  In fact, already `evaluate_candidates` [is defined](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/42aff4e2edd8e8887478f6ff1628f27de97be6a3/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py#L784) assuming that the hyperparameter points live in an iterable `candidate_params`; the `ParameterGrid` does all the hard work there, but in your case you can just feed your list directly.

Comment: Thank you for your comment!  Most probably BaseSearchCV is the class I was looking for